# ヘッダーにプロトタイプ宣言をまとめて書く

Tags: c, zsh

関数がかかれたファイルが20くらいあります。
そのプロトタイプ宣言をヘッダーファイルに書きたいのですが、シェルスクリプトのコマンドでまとめて書くことはできますか？

ファイルは１ファイル関数が一つ1行目に#include, 3行目から関数名がかかれています。

Comment: お使いのOSはなんでしょう?

Comment: macつかってますです

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew でも MacPorts でも [cproto](https://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html) というツールのパッケージが利用可能です。「3行目を抜き出して行末に`;`を足す」というだけならOS標準コマンドだけでもできると思いますが、コーディングスタイルを変えると動かなくなったりするので、けっきょくは既存のツールを使うほうが楽だと思います。

zsh のソースのビルドをしたときもそんなことしてたな、と思い出して調べてみましたが、[zsh は自前のツール](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/makepro.awk)でプロトタイプを生成していますね。

参考までに、[MSVC にはプロトタイプ生成フラグ `/Zg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/zg-generate-function-prototypes?view=vs-2019)がありました。